# CollapsiblePanelExtender should not collapse on AutoPostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, autopostback, collapsiblepanelextender

I've got an asp.net page with some `CollapsiblePanelExtender` which is collapsed by default and contains CheckBoxes.
My problem is that when I expand one and check a CheckBox an `AutoPostBack` event is firing and my `CollapsiblePanelExtender` is collapsed again.

Is there a way to let the `CollapsiblePanelExtender` expand when I click a CheckBox with just C# and asp.net? I don't want to use JavaScript here.

Here is the configuration of my control:

```
CollapsiblePanelExtender cpe = new CollapsiblePanelExtender();
cpe.ID = "cpe" + headerName;
cpe.TargetControlID = headerName + "Body";
cpe.CollapsedSize = 0;
cpe.Collapsed = true;
cpe.ExpandControlID = headerName + "Header";
cpe.CollapseControlID = headerName + "Header";
cpe.AutoCollapse = false;
cpe.AutoExpand = false;
cpe.ScrollContents = false;
cpe.ExpandDirection = CollapsiblePanelExpandDirection.Vertical;
cpe.SuppressPostBack = false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It collapses because the html is replaced with what comes from the server after the postback, therefore, the `CollapsiblePanelExtender` returns to the default state.

If you can use UpdatePanels, consider the following:

Put the `CollapsiblePanelExtender` inside an `UpdatePanel`. Set the `UpdatePanel` `UpdateMode="Conditional"` and `ChildrenAsTriggers="false"`.

The client state of the html inside that updatepanel will be maintained after the Postback because the panel will not update.

If you ever need it to update, you could update it manually by calling `updatePanel.Update()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But when I try to add a `CollapsiblePanelExtender` control to the `UpdatePanel` I get an unexpected error when I want to open the site. It works perfect with other controls but not with a `CollapsiblePanelExtender`.

Comment: I could only see the "unexpected error" site from SharePoint so I tried to debug but the debugger didn't show me an error.. Now I've an `UpdatePanel` without any control in it but the `CollapsiblePanelExtender` didn't collapse on `AutoPostBack` anymore.